# View Product page magento

Tags: magento

in magento when I click on a product I go to

```
www.mysite.com/product.html
```

How I can change to

```
www.mysite.com/sometext/product.html
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

1. Go To Menu Admin > Catalog > URL Rewrite Management
2. Click on "Add New URL Rewrite" button
3. Select "Create URL Rewrite:" For Product
4. Filter your product in grid and select product
5. Click on "Skip select category" button at the end of the page
6. Change request path to "sometext/product.html"